Need to restart foreground service after clear all recent apps
When user pressed or swiped the clear all recent apps the service was stopped and the notification was gone. But I need to keep restarting this service. I am using Kotlin
This is a offline application.
have any suggestion for this?

If the user has cleared the app you cannot restart the service. In fact there is no scenario where you can keep a service running forever
